# Add a click function to a toggle function?

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have an accordian NAV setup with collapsible tabs and toggling +/- buttons.

I'm trying to make my 'tab' DIVs clickable. I added the following function around part of my code and removed repeditive toggle() functions, but it's still not quite working right--

**UPDATED**

```
$('.tabs').click(function() {
    }
)
```

My HTML

```
<div id="tab1" class="tabs">NEWS [<a href="#" class="button" id="plus1">more</a>]</div>
<div class="expandable" id="one">
<p>This is placeholder text.</p></div>

<div id="tab2" class="tabs">EVENTS [<a href="#" class="button" id="plus2">more</a>]</div>
<div class="expandable" id="two">
<p>This is placeholder text.</p></div>
```

And my javascript

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".expandable").hide();
$(".button").show();

$('.tabs').click(function() {  // added new

  $('.button').toggle(function(){
      $(".expandable").slideDown(
        function(){
          $(".button").text("less")
        }
      );
  },function(){
      $(".expandable").slideUp(
      function(){
          $(".button").text("more")
      }
      );
  });

}); // end of click
});

});
```

I had it originally setup with a toggle() function for each tab, but I was told not to do that. I struggle with JS syntax so I'm not sure where to go at this point.

Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, do not create multiple togglefunction `$('#plus1').toggle` `$('#plus2').toggle` rather assign class to them and create one `$('.plus').toggle` this will minimize and make your code efficient (maintainable)
For more information on how to go with it Refer [slide toggle example](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)
It gives a good example on how to deal with this Toggle function. you'll have an idea on how to use it. Proceed with it, if have any problem then do post :)

**UPDATED**
Assign a class to your DIV which needs to be made clickable (say `tabs`)
In your JS write this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tabs').click(function() {
      alert('the div is clicked');
      alert($(this).html());  // This is nothing but the content of clicked DIV
    });
});
```

**EDITED**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.expandable').hide();
});
```

Or give a style sheet

```
<style type="text/css">
.expandable {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate your advice on simplifying my code. I'll definitely look into that as I haven't done what you're suggesting before. BUT that doesn't actually answer my original question, which is how do I make the DIVs clickable? Should I use click()? And how?

Comment: OK, I placed `$('.tabs').click(function() {});` around my code but I'm messing up something. It loads with both expanded and [more] showing.. Then it resets and seems to work the way it's supposed to after I've clicked a few times.. Like I said I think my problems are with syntax...

Comment: give a style to it. By default the style should be `display: none;`

Comment: I think you should update your question so that I can understand what changes you've made. Else accept this answer and open a new question with your new problems so it will be better answered by others as well